# When 2 Jointed White Neutral Wires are separated, one becomes Hot?

Tags: electrical

Electrical Socket in Ceiling Issue

I wanted to replace a ceiling light in the foyer after 7 years. The ceiling light electrical socket has 3 wires.

- Two Black wires joined together (capped & not used here).
- One Red wire connected to light. It becomes Live when switch is turned ON.
- Two White wires joined together and connected to light. It stays Neutral when switch is turned On or Off.
  PROBLEM:
  When the 2 jointed white wires are separated, one becomes HOT.

Comment: How are you finding one white becomes hot?  What test did you do?  How are the wires connected at the switch?  Should have a black and red on the switch and the white wire capped off.  The white is required to be at the switch box incase you want a smart switch in the future.

Comment: Why were you disconnecting neutrals, wires, when the power was still on? That's a good way to get knocked on your butt.

Comment: Sounds normal to me.  *By the way, this is WHY the neutral wire is insulated.*  Now why are you doing this work with the circuit live?

Comment: If you are using one of those stupid contactless phase tester, they are wrong 50% of time. Use multimeter.

Comment: @Ruskes The "stupid contactless phase testers" are an very useful *safety* tool. They are no substitute for a multimeter, but they are really useful when used as designed and when you understand how things work.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I know, if you hold them 1 inch away from hot wire they will indicate positive. Now try that in a junction box.

Comment: @Ruskes Actually, one of the key uses is to make sure *everything* in a junction box is dead. If you have multiple circuits in a box, which can happen easily enough and totally legally, being able to test to double check that *everything* is dead is a huge safety feature.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact what do you do if you are actually trying to find the hot wire., and not just kill everything in the junction box. It will give you false positive

Comment: @ruskies. I have never seen a non contact phase detector, all the non contact detectors do is detect voltage not phase. Unless it is a current clamp that goes around the wire then it can tell what the amperage is without contact.

Answer (score 2):

**Does the light work on the switch as expected when connected to red and both whites?**

Presumably the one you removed did.

If so, the "white becomes hot" is an error on your part.

Could be it's a neutral from a different fixture on the same circuit which is turned on, and then it actually will become hot (and its fixture off) when you disconnect it from neutral, because hot is passing through the other fixture, but *you cut the neutral path for it.*

Could also be using the wrong method to determine what's hot and getting fooled by induced voltage.

When you remove a light fixture which was working, ONLY disconnect the light fixture, and connect the new light fixture to the same places the working light fixture was removed from. Don't start yanking things apart that don't need to be taken apart to replace the fixture, especially if you don't know exactly where they are going, and what they are doing there.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the "hot" neutral is actually connected to a **live circuit**. Two neutrals connected to the light fixture indicates one going to the panel and one going on to another fixture or receptacle. If that fixture/receptacle is *on* when you do this test, it *will* show some voltage when disconnected, as the current on that part of the circuit is trying to get back "home". Really no different (except a load in between) than a hot wire that is not connected - use an NCVT on the hot pin of a receptacle and it will detect voltage even though nothing is plugged in to the receptacle.

This raises two possible safety issues:

- Generally speaking, you want to work on circuits when they are off. The NCVT is more of a *safety* tool than a diagnostic tool. It can be used to figure out which wire(s) in a box are live (as opposed to the safety aspect of "is *any* wire live") but you need to be careful when doing that.
- MWBC, Multi-Wire Branch Circuits, can really surprise people. That may or may not be the case here, but with MWBCs there (a) is the chance of unexpected live wires if the two halves of the circuit are not on a double-breaker or handle-tied breaker pair, and (b) it is extra important to keep the neutrals together, because otherwise you could end up with some serious problems.

Comment: It's not phantom voltage, the circuit continues.  That's a nice feature of post-2011 switch loops, you can continue the circuit through the switch.

Comment: There is definitely nothing phantom about it. It’s actual power returning from another load.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue and the reason multiwire branch circuits require a handle tie or since 08 they have.

You can get shocked on a neutral yes by 120v

If there is a hot then a device even a radio, night light , wall wart or anything on the circuit when the Grounded conductor is removed now there is power trying to find its way back to the source,

the measured voltage to ground can be 120v and it can have the potential of the device that is plugged in.

There is also the possibility of phantom voltage this voltage has no potential and is not a shock hazard so there are ways to see voltage on the grounded conductor when the wire is removed from the grounding source.

Comment: It's not phantom voltage, the circuit continues.

Comment: @ruskes, I defined phantom voltage it has nothing to do if the circuit continues you can create phantom voltage with a length of wire standing under a power line or close proximity to another live wire, phantom voltage has no potential this is why it is called phantom

Comment: I did not say that 
@Harper - Reinstate Monica- said it.

Comment: @ruskes the first comment below the answer is from you. “It's not phantom voltage, the circuit continues” so you put that there and that is what I was responding to. Maybe time for me to let the internet only electricians have at it again.